"Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey" despite generation of unique keys
I have a screen where the user is shown multiple recommendations or in this case just items with TextFormFields. Those items are stacked above each other using the package SwipableStack. For each item the user can swipe right to accept or swipe left to dismiss (it's comparable to dating apps like Tinder). When he wants to accept the item, the input of the TextFormField is validated.
Issue:
The initial build works perfectly fine. After I accept the first item, it is removed as it should. But after that, the following error occurs multiple times when rebuilding the screen:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

The key [LabeledGlobalKey<FormState>#9dc26] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were:
- Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0), dependencies: [Directionality], renderObject: RenderPadding#386b3)
- Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0), dependencies: [Directionality], renderObject: RenderPadding#0a341)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3205:13)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
#2      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3149:20)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
#4      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3144:36)
#5      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3213:6)
#6      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3267:11)
#7      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3342:8)
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1169:19)
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:468:5)
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1397:15)
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1318:9)
#12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1176:5)
#13     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#14     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:419:5)
#15     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
====================================================================================================

I suppose that there are still old instances somewhere in the Widget tree that lead to those issues. But I can not figure it out how this can be solved.
Here's the current code:
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:investiquo/1-general/services/formatter.dart';
import 'package:investiquo/1-general/templates/styling.dart';
import 'package:swipable_stack/swipable_stack.dart';

class RecommendationsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Controller is irrelevant for this instance
  static late SwipableStackController controller;

  const RecommendationsScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<RecommendationsScreen> createState() => _RecommendationsScreenState();
}

class _RecommendationsScreenState extends State<RecommendationsScreen> {
  final int swipeActionDuration = 750;
  int noOfRemovedItems = 0;
  List<Widget>? recommendationTiles;
  List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKeys = [];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [
    {
      'label': 'ABC',
    },
    {
      'label': 'DEF',
    },
    {
      'label': 'GHI',
    },
    {
      'label': 'JKL',
    },
  ];

  void updateFormKeys() {
    /// Update no. of formKeys if there are either too many or not enough for each item
    if (formKeys.length != items.length) {
      formKeys = List.generate(
        items.length,
        (_) => GlobalKey<FormState>(),
      );
    }
  }

  List<Widget> currentRecommendationWidgets({
    required AppLocalizations t,
  }) {
    List<Widget> recommendationItems = [];

    updateFormKeys();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      recommendationItems.add(
        Container(
          color: kTileBackgroundColor,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultScreenPaddingAllSides),
          child: Form(
            key: formKeys[i],
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                label: Text(items[i]['label']),
              ),
              validator: (String? value) {
                final String adjustedValue = removeAllSeparators(
                  value,
                  Localizations.localeOf(context).toLanguageTag(),
                );

                if (adjustedValue.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a value';
                }

                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return recommendationItems;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    formKeys = List.generate(
      items.length,
      (_) => GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AppLocalizations t = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

    recommendationTiles ??= currentRecommendationWidgets(
      t: t,
    );

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultScreenPaddingAllSides),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          items.isNotEmpty
              ? Positioned.fill(
                  child: SwipableStack(
                    allowVerticalSwipe: false,
                    stackClipBehaviour: Clip.none,
                    overlayBuilder: (context, properties) {
                      /// Overlay that indicates to the user if he is about to accept or dismiss the current item
                      final opacity = min(properties.swipeProgress, 1.0);
                      final isRight = properties.direction == SwipeDirection.right;

                      return properties.swipeProgress >= 0.15
                          ? Opacity(
                              opacity: opacity,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  isRight
                                      ? Positioned(
                                          left: 0,
                                          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultScreenPaddingAllSides),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                color: kTextInputOutline,
                                                width: 1.0,
                                              ),
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                            ),
                                            child: Text(
                                              t.recommendationGeneralImplementLabel,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: kDefaultHeaderSize,
                                                color: kSuccessColor,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : Positioned(
                                          right: 0,
                                          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultScreenPaddingAllSides),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                color: kTextInputOutline,
                                                width: 1.0,
                                              ),
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                            ),
                                            child: Text(
                                              t.recommendationGeneralIgnoreLabel,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: kDefaultHeaderSize,
                                                color: kFailureColor,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container();
                    },
                    horizontalSwipeThreshold: 0.8,
                    onWillMoveNext: (i, direction) {
                      /// If the user wants to accept the item the TextFormField needs to be validated. Proceed only if it returns true
                      bool isLeft = direction == SwipeDirection.left;
                      bool isRight = direction == SwipeDirection.right;
                      bool isValidated = formKeys[0].currentState?.validate() ?? false;

                      return isLeft || (isRight && isValidated);
                    },
                    onSwipeCompleted: (i, direction) async {
                      /// To simplify the matter we only want to print to the console depending on the chosen action
                      if (direction == SwipeDirection.right) {
                        print('Accepted');
                      } else if (direction == SwipeDirection.left) {
                        print('Declined');
                      }

                      /// After the swipe was completed we want to remove the top card so that instead of for example label "ABC" now "DEF" is shown
                      items.removeAt(0);

                      noOfRemovedItems += 1;

                      /// Update recommendationTile according to the new number of items
                      setState(() {
                        recommendationTiles = currentRecommendationWidgets(
                          t: t,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    builder: (context, properties) {
                      final int currentIndex = (properties.index - noOfRemovedItems).clamp(
                        0,
                        recommendationTiles!.length - 1,
                      );

                      return recommendationTiles![currentIndex];
                    },
                  ),
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks a lot for any help! Really appreciate it.
All the best,
Alex
Expectation:
The user can go through the whole stack of items. For each item the respective validator is triggered when the user swipes right.
Actual result:
The first swipe works just fine. After that, when items[1] is supposed to load or to take over the top of the stack, the "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey" error occurs.
I have tried different locations of the Form widget and to generate new GlobalKeys on each rebuild.
